# Filter XML via url without code

Tags: xml, http, url

Is it possible to filter an XML file via url?

Let's say we have this XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <i id="4711">
    <no>4711</no>
    <p>47,50</p>
  </i>
  <i id="4712">
    <no>4712</no>
    <p>22,75</p>
  </i>
</root>
```

Let's say I want to retrieve `id 4711` directly via URL. So I don't have to make any webservice or any code but the browser can understand and process it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly with your browser its not possible. You need something to parse the XML and select the data.

When you don't want to parse it with an interpreted language like PHP or something else you can use Javascript for example.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```